# Python Resampling Implementation like Matlab's Signal Toolbox's Resampling Function

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, scipy

The [Scipy Resample](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.resample.html#scipy.signal.resample) appears to not use any filters nor use the same method as [Matlab Resample](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/resample.html).

Any idea on how to match Matlab's resample method in Python? Is there a function already that I have not found?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: `resample` is implemented in Matlab code. Use `edit resample` to look at the code. If you can figure out what it does, you can reimplement it in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [scikits.samplerate](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scikits.samplerate).

A simple usage is available [here](http://www.ar.media.kyoto-u.ac.jp/members/david/softwares/samplerate/sphinx/overview.html#a-simple-example).